# Cyclotomic fields and $Q$-linearly independence

Tags: nt.number-theory

For each odd prime $p$, choose an arbitrary $x_p \in \mathbb Q(\zeta_p) \smallsetminus \mathbb Q$, where $\zeta_p = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p}}$. Is it always true that the set $\{x_p : p \in \mathbb P\}$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: Yes, it is true. $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)\cap\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)=\mathbb{Q}$ if $(m,n)=1$. Look at ramification or use Galois theory in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{mn})$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)\cap\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)=\mathbb{Q}$ also follows from $[\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_m]=\varphi(n)$ and multiplicativity of Euler's totient function $\varphi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think everything is clear now by George Lowther's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61123/cyclotomic-fields-and-q-linearly-independence#comment153670_61123), reproduced here with two minor typos corrected:

> $\mathbb Q(\zeta_m) \cap \mathbb Q(\zeta_n) = \mathbb Q$ also follows from $[\mathbb Q[\zeta_m] : \mathbb Q] = \varphi(m)$ and multiplicativity of Euler's totient function $\varphi$.